# Cannot access directory in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I'm backing up IIS7 configuration with the appcmd utility. The backup goes on well, and the folder with the backup's name is created in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\backup as expected. However, although I can see the folder from Windows Explorer, I cannot see it from other tools (like the command prompt or my backup utility). In Windows Explorer the folder icon appears with a superimposed lock, which I don't know what means. I checked the folder permissions and I couldn't find anything particular (SYSTEM and Administrators have all permissions, owner is Administrators).

I actually solved the immediate problem by sharing the backup directory and accesing the share, but I want to understand this strange set of permissions that keeps other programs from accessing or even see the folder. Would anyone care to explain it to me?

Thanks in advance,
Guillermo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about x64 OS is certain paths are only viewable with a 64-bit process. I suspect the programs you use to view it are 32-bit processes.

If you wish to use your 32-bit programs to view the folder path, you may need to create some symbolic links, as explained here

http://icelava.net/forums/thread/5391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question.  From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546773.aspx

The files are encrypted.

You can create two types of metabase backups:

- Portable backups - When you create a portable backup, you provide a password that is used by IIS to encrypt the backup files. After the backup file is encrypted, you cannot change the password of the backup file.
- Nonportable backups - When you create a nonportable backup, you do not supply a password. Therefore, IIS encrypts nonportable backup files with a blank password, which allows any member of the administrators group to restore the metabase by using nonportable backup files. Only the blank password and secure properties are encrypted; all other information within the backup file is plaintext.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo, but I don't think that's the case. Neither the directory or the files have the "encrypt content" checkbox checked. The links you provided apply to IIS6, which still had the .vbs administration scripts. IIS6 backups could indeed be encrypted, but they could be nevertheless copied from disk to disk and accessed from any backup or file management utility. IIS7 appcmd utility doesn't support encrypting the files, and the files it creates cannot be copied with a simple COPY command or simple backup utilities, although windows explorer can access them. I want to know why.

Comment: sorry Guillermo, I will take a look on my iis7 box.